# What bonus does the Frost Fang give, in Hand of Fate?

Tags: hand-of-fate

I've been playing Hand of Fate recently; I'm, currently, at the *Queen of Scales* boss, and am presented with a choice: keep using *Thunderstrike*(with 35 electric based damage) or buy a *Frost Fang* (with 25 ice based damage).

Since I'm gonna encounter quite a few lizard man and lava golems, I wonder if the Frost Fang, even with a lower damage, would be a better choice. So, the question is: since the Frost Fang does "more damage" to the enemies I'll encounter, should I buy it? And what does "more damage" really mean?

Comment: I think the Frost fang gives an ability to freeze enemies around you on use. I don't know if elemental effects do more damage to lava golems and such.

Comment: @Lyrion Yes, in the description of the weapon, it says that; however, ever you first find anything in this game, there is a _different_ text that shows up, and, in this case, it says that the frost fang does more damage to lizardman and lava golem - but it does say how much the bonus is.

Comment: I can't find anything other than "bonus damage" with no numbers to speak of.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... Thanks anyway